# Java Native Invocation without C++ wrapper lib

Tags: java, java-native-interface

is there a way to invoke functions in native libraries (Windows .dll's, Linux .so's), withouth having to write a C++ wrapper dealing with JEnv and "this" pointers?

I'm missing C#-alike functionality in this regard, where one can link with native functions easily without writing bridge libraries, leaving up to the compiler marshaling details.

Thanks,
Emilio.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use Java Native Access, [JNA](http://jna.java.net/), to do exactly what you want.

Note that the usual wrapper library wouldn't be written in C++, but in C.

Answer (score 1):

I hated having to write JNI code and looked at JNA but it didn't seemed to be that widely used and might present a potential performance problem. Use [SWIG](http://www.swig.org/) instead. Once you are up and running it doesn't take that long to script it and get it generating your JNI interface code for you.